# Do we get same users in reports.userUsageReport.get and directory.users.list

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

In Google Admin API,

For a domain, lets assume `today is 1st Jan, 2015`. I performed case [1] `today`. 5 days later I performed case [2] for report date (`1st Jan 2015`) since case 2 data is not available instantly.

Cases:

1. Retrieve list of users from `directory.users.list` (`showDeleted = False`)
2. Retrieve list of users from `reports.userUsageReport.get` (`userKey = all`)

Will the list of users in case [1] and [2] be same? If not, what's the difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With directory.users.list, you will get all the users in the domain if you give the domain name. But with reports.userUsageReport.get, you will get all the users with the recent activites. If user has no recent activity, then user wont show up in the list.

If userKey=all in reports.userUsageReport.get, it means you get all the users with recent activites. If you give userkey, you will get recent activities of that particular user. Let me know if you have any questions.